# Nginx url rewrite fine tuning

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble fine tuning a regex for Nginx url rewrite rules, What I am trying to do is take the first two pieces of the url and convert them to variables (nothing too fancy, and should be simple).

e.g. I type in http://www.webserver.com/piece1/piece2 and get http://www.webserver.com/rewtest.php??val1=piece1&val2=piece2

So far I have:

```
    location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/? /rewtest.php?val1=$1&val2=$2 last;
return   404;}

}
```

which does seem to work.  The problem is if the user types http://www.webserver.com/piece1/piece2/  it gives val 1 as piece1/piece2 (as 1 variable, not 2).

Also if the user were to type http://www.webserver.com/piece1/ I currently get piece1 in var 1, which is great.  BUT if the user types http://www.webserver.com/piece1 it gives me an error and I'd like to get the same (var 1=piece1).

Any help greatly appreciated as I am new to regexs!

Comment: Maybe / needs to be escaped somehow, e.g. as \/?

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if / is also recognized by "."...try:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /rewtest.php?val1=$1&val2=$2 last;
  return   404;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but at the moment it just gives me a 404 :(

Comment: maybe use [a-zA-Z0-9-] if your domain/site contains 0-9 or "-"

Comment: does it work with the updated regex? This will only work if the URL really contains 2 parts. Otherwise you may need an additional rewrite rule?

Comment: with an if statement?  hmmm, let me try (url may contain 1 or 2 parts).  Let me try it out!  Thanks for the help!